i have problem on sending email using mailtrap
Connection could not be established with host "sandbox.smtp.mailtrap.io:2525":  Unable to connect to sandbox.smtp.mailtrap.io:2525 (A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond)

There is too little information to get an understanding kindly edit your question. If you can share your env for mail and mailtrap config.

This would be a connection issue either on your server, or on mailtrap's end. There's nothing we'll be able to help you with here.

There the full doncumentation about how to use mailTrap with laravel
Laravel+Mailtrap

SMTP details must be wrong check what are you passing in the mailer object.
